# Pbixrefresher for Power BI Desktop report refresh/publish error

Tags: python, powerbi

I am trying to refresh power b.i. more frequently than current capability of gateway schedule refresh.

I found this:
https://github.com/dubravcik/pbixrefresher-python

Installed and verified I have all required packages installed to run.
Right now it works fine until the end - where after it refreshes a Save function seems to execute correctly - but the report does not save - and when it tries Publish function - a prompt is created asking if user would like to save and there is a timeout.

I have tried increasing the time-out argument and adding more wait time in the routine (along with a couple of other suggested ideas from the github issues thread).

Below is what cmd looks like along with the error - I also added the Main routine of the pbixrefresher file in case there is a different way to save (hotkeys) or something worth trying.  I tried this both as my user and admin in CMD - but wasn't sure if it's possible a permissions setting could block the report from saving.  Thank you for reading any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Starting Power BI
Waiting 15 sec
Identifying Power BI window
Refreshing
Waiting for refresh end (timeout in 100000 sec)
Saving
Publish
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 258, in __resolve_control
criteria)
File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 458, in wait_until_passes
raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"main", mod_spec)
File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Python36\Scripts\pbixrefresher.exe_main.py", line 9, in
File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pbixrefresher\pbixrefresher.py", line 77, in main
publish_dialog.child_window(title = WORKSPACE, found_index=0).click_input()
File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 379, in getattribute
ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 261, in __resolve_control
raise e.original_exception
File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes
func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 222, in __get_ctrl
ctrl = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**ctrl_criteria))
File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element
raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'auto_id': 'KoPublishToGroupDialog', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - 'Simple - Power BI Desktop', WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.1bb715_r6_ad1, 8914246>, 'backend': 'uia'}
```

The main routine from pbixrefresher:

```
def main():   
    # Parse arguments from cmd
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("workbook", help = "Path to .pbix file")
    parser.add_argument("--workspace", help = "name of online Power BI service work space to publish in", default = "My workspace")
    parser.add_argument("--refresh-timeout", help = "refresh timeout", default = 30000, type = int)
    parser.add_argument("--no-publish", dest='publish', help="don't publish, just save", default = True, action = 'store_false' )
    parser.add_argument("--init-wait", help = "initial wait time on startup", default = 15, type = int)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    timings.after_clickinput_wait = 1
    WORKBOOK = args.workbook
    WORKSPACE = args.workspace
    INIT_WAIT = args.init_wait
    REFRESH_TIMEOUT = args.refresh_timeout

    # Kill running PBI
    PROCNAME = "PBIDesktop.exe"
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        # check whether the process name matches
        if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
            proc.kill()
    time.sleep(3)

    # Start PBI and open the workbook
    print("Starting Power BI")
    os.system('start "" "' + WORKBOOK + '"')
    print("Waiting ",INIT_WAIT,"sec")
    time.sleep(INIT_WAIT)

    # Connect pywinauto
    print("Identifying Power BI window")
    app = Application(backend = 'uia').connect(path = PROCNAME)
    win = app.window(title_re = '.*Power BI Desktop')
    time.sleep(5)
    win.wait("enabled", timeout = 300)
    win.Save.wait("enabled", timeout = 300)
    win.set_focus()
    win.Home.click_input()
    win.Save.wait("enabled", timeout = 300)
    win.wait("enabled", timeout = 300)

    # Refresh
    print("Refreshing")
    win.Refresh.click_input()
    #wait_win_ready(win)
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Waiting for refresh end (timeout in ", REFRESH_TIMEOUT,"sec)")
    win.wait("enabled", timeout = REFRESH_TIMEOUT)

    # Save
    print("Saving")
    type_keys("%1", win)
    #wait_win_ready(win)
    time.sleep(5)
    win.wait("enabled", timeout = REFRESH_TIMEOUT)

    # Publish
    if args.publish:
        print("Publish")
        win.Publish.click_input()
        publish_dialog = win.child_window(auto_id = "KoPublishToGroupDialog")
        publish_dialog.child_window(title = WORKSPACE).click_input()
        publish_dialog.Select.click()
        try:
            win.Replace.wait('visible', timeout = 10)
        except Exception:
            pass
        if win.Replace.exists():
            win.Replace.click_input()
        win["Got it"].wait('visible', timeout = REFRESH_TIMEOUT)
        win["Got it"].click_input()

    #Close
    print("Exiting")
    win.close()

    # Force close
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
            proc.kill()

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Update on this - I have verified that in the type_keys function executed in the Saving portion of the module it is entering Alt+1 "type_keys("%1", win)" - this does not save a power bi report presently - when I enter it manually it creates an alert noise which I also hear during the script run - only hotkey I could find that works manually is Ctrl+S - I tested replacing above with "type_keys("^s", win) - this did not work however.

Comment: The question looks not clear. Failed line `publish_dialog.child_window(title = WORKSPACE, found_index=0).click_input()` is not present in the main procedure posted here. Please edit your question to figure out the problem or delete it if the root cause is posted in another question to avoid duplication. I take care about "pywinauto" tag statistics as a maintainer of the library. So accepted answers and good clear questions is always good to me. But please note it's a hobby project so I can't cover everything without community's help.

Comment: Hey I removed the pywinauto tag - it is not a pywinauto issue here - issue seems to be that the power bi desktop publisher no longer uses the same hotkeys -

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, but using  "win.type_keys("^S")" solved.

Comment: Can you elaborate? As it is your answer isn't very useful.  Providing more context may be the key to making promoting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally figured out what was happening. My prior post about version compatibility did not solve the issue.

It's a very strange bug - `pywinauto` sometimes *misses* the correct button. I was able to reproduce this multiple times, although it didn't happen *every* time - it sometimes happened on `win.Refresh.click_input()`, sometimes on `win.Publish.click_input()` This was why the popup dialog `'KoPublishToGroupDialog'` cannot be found after clicking Publish and the script fails. This also indicates that the Refresh wouldn't work consistently because the script doesn't check if the dialog opens - it just waits for a predetermined amount of time to allow the refresh to finish.

I implemented a check to see if the dialog window actually opened, e.g.

```
if not win.child_window(auto_id="KoPublishToGroupDialog").exists():
     raise AttributeError("publish dialog failed to open")
```

along with a retry and maximum wait loop but this *didn't* fix the issue. What finally worked was much simpler:

The toolbar of the PowerBI Desktop application has two modes, expanded and small. The default setup is to use expanded mode - you can minimize the toolbar to use small icons with the small arrow in the top right of PowerBI Desktop (bottom right in the pic below).

BEFORE:

[image: expanded toolbar (errors occur)]

AFTER

[image: minimized toolbar (works)]

This seems to take care of the `pywinauto` bug (or whatever actually causes it) where the Refresh or Publish buttons are missed when clicking them.

Hope this helps someone, it took way too long to figure this out.

---UPDATE---:

Unfortunately this was NOT the full solution, what I didn't realize (and probably had a lot to do with *missing the buttons*) was the virtual machine's screen resolution I'm using to run this script was *resized* when the connection was closed. I'm using the `tscon.exe` solution to connect the desktop session to the console via a batch script so it isn't shut down after disconnecting. To keep the resolution I installed `qres.exe` (added to PATH) and added it to the batch script:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (
  %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
  timeout 5
  qres /X 1920 /Y 1080 /C 32
)
```

I use this script to disconnect from the remote desktop session but keep the screen resolution. I also set up my RDP client to connect using this resolution.

At the moment I'm still not 100% sure what else might be necessary to get this to work consistently. For example after setting up the new fixed resolution I had to open PowerBI Desktop manually and set it to windowed (non-maximized) mode so it wouldn't *completely* miss the Refresh button (it was at least close before). My last test (staying connected) worked, disconnected from RDP it still seems to have issues though.